# How to add an open path in Clipperlib

Tags: c++, clipperlib

The document of Clipper say that 'Subject' paths may be either open (lines) or closed (polygons) or even a mixture of both.Yet when I try to add an open path in the class of ClipperLib::Clipper, it always got error.The source code are as follows:

`ClipperLib::Clipper splitArea;   //Declare an object of Clipper
  splitArea.Clear();
  ClipperLib::Path Sub;   //Declare an object of path
  Sub<<ClipperLib::IntPoint(-1000*1000000,0*1000000)   <<ClipperLib::IntPoint(0*1000000,1000*1000000);   //add a line in path
  splitArea.AddPath(Sub,ClipperLib::ptSubject,false);  //this line is error
  ...`

Comment: Near the top of clipper.hpp uncomment the following ... #define use_lines

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much.My program  went works under your advise.